# Is there a way to use a wildcard with a suffix for DNS records in Cloudflare?

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

Suppose there is a domain `.example.com`. I want to separate it into 2 parts
eg:

`*-new.example.com` -----> IP1

such that all dns with suffix `-new` point to IP1

`*-old.example.com` -----> IP2

such that all dns with suffix `-old` point to IP2

I tried this but giving `*-new.example.com` in cloudfare is not sending the request to IP1

Is there a way that this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can create page rules (up to 3 on the free tier) to do the matching.

Define a rule saying: `If the URL matches: *-new.example.com` then `Forwarding URL: IP1`

Here you will get some examples with more complex configs:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/page-rules/recommended-page-rules-to-consider/

Answer (score 0):

A DNS wildcard is the form `*.example.com`, the first label must be just `*` and nothing else.

`*-new.example.com` is not a DNS wildcard and won't work as such.